# d2: Calling writefln in D shared libraries from C side

Tags: shared-libraries, d

I'm trying to quickstart with dynamic shared libraries in D, but I'm having a problem.

I'm building following code with `dmd -shared ./testlib.d`:

```
module testlib;

import std.c.stdio;

extern (C) export int hello(int a) {
    printf("Number is %d", a);

    return (a + 1);
}
```

It builds fine, and works. But when I'm trying to make use of following more D'ish source:

```
module testlib;

import std.stdio;

extern (C) export int hello(int a) {
    writefln("Number is %d", a);

    return (a + 1);
}
```

It fails with segmentation fault once I'm trying to call `hello`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling `hello` using Python:

```
import ctypes

testlib = ctypes.CDLL('testlib.dylib');

print (testlib.hello(10))
```

**UPD1:** Seems that I also cannot use Phobos functions like `std.conv.to!(string)`.

**UPD2:** There is no such problem on Windows, everything seems to work fine. Mac OS X suffers from this.

**UPD3:** Possibly, this is connected with GC. I must somehow initialize GC, but core.memory.GC.enable() still fails with segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is simple, yet brilliant:

```
static import core.runtime;

extern (C) export void init() { // to be called once after loading shared lib
    core.runtime.Runtime.initialize();
}

extern (C) export void done() { // to be called before unloading shared lib
    core.runtime.Runtime.terminate();
}
```

Possibly, there are ways in Linux and Mac OS X to call these functions automagically, but I'm satisfied with even this.

Comment: Maybe, use RAII instead? so, create new class `DRuntime` and add your `init` function to constructor, `done` - to destructor. So, client just create object of this class - and it makes all job for us.

Comment: But what should I do if client is not written in D? E.g. how can C core instantiate DRuntime descendant?

Comment: If you need explicitly C, what haven't C++ `class`, `new`, constructors/destructors support - just use your `init/done` functions in usual C-style. And you can look at http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html, if not yet.